# Substring to Get value only after first occurrence of : in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I have data in below format in an Oracle table column:

```
ABC:XYZ
ABC:MNO:LMO
ABC:MNO:LRT:RNO
PQR:TYU:MNO
```

I want to have data in below format i.e to have  distinct first string after first occurrence of `:`:

```
 XYZ
 MNO
 TYU
```

I can get the value for first record using below query

```
 select REGEXP_SUBSTR('ABC:XYZ','[^:]+$') from dual
```

But I am unable to get it for others if there are more than one `:` in a column value.

Any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two more arguments:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('ABC:XYZ', '[^:]+', 1, 2)
from dual;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d16b62da96708d9219ef6ecd4062e91b) is a db<>fiddle.